# TypeScript:Undefined value when get value in table

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get value of table in typeScript, ? 
[image: Result of console.log(jsonUsers)]

**myComponent.ts :**

```
let jsonUsers = [];
getUser() {

// When I do this console ==> I get response on the picture
 console.log(this.jsonUsers );

// Now I want to get value of code and label but it is not worked 
 console.log(jsonUsers.length); // ==> 0
 for (var index = 0; index < this.jsonUsers .length; index++) {
      var element = this.jsonUsers [0];
      console.log(element.code);
 }
```

[image: MyCode]

Comment: Please turn `this.jsonUsers .length` to `this.jsonUsers.length`. I´m not sure if it works that way but never have seen it with white space

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Oh and your console.log is wrong it should be `console.log(this.jsonUsers.length);`, you have forgotten this

Comment: Thx, It is an error typing (but it is this.jsonUsers.length), My error is that in first one : the length is 0 and i don't know the reason

Comment: How is that wrong @Doomenik?

Comment: @Faisal and user, inside your console.log you forgot `this` . Without you try to get an variable jsonUsers from the function itself, this one does not exist and has a length of O. `This` stores a reference of your component with which you can acess variables defined outside from your function.

Comment: Ok, I added this.jsonUsers.length but I got anyway 0 ...

Comment: Can you provide us the ouput of  `console.log(this.jsonUsers );` directly from this line

Comment: `[]
0 : {code: "IDV", label: "Identification de véhicule"}
1 : {id: 1, code: "IDV", label: "Vehicle", status: "actif"}
2 : {id: 2, code: "VCV", label: "Conduire", status: "actif"}
3 : {id: 3, code: "VID", label: "Identité", status: "actif"}
4 : {id: 4, code: "ATJ", label: "Antécédents", status: "inactif"}
length : 8
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: Strange, seems correct. The `[] 0:` is a little bit strange. Could you try to console.log(this.jsonUsers[0]);

Comment: the `0 :` is just the index of the first element .. like after `1 2 ...` ... and when I tried console.log(this.jsonUsers[0]) I got `undefined` ...

Comment: This was just a trial, this means somehow your jsonUsers is still undefined. The `0:`Is not what seems to wrong it´s from what I know the `[]` normally it should be like this: ' [0: ......... ]' I have never seen that the brackets are opening and closing before.

Comment: Ok I got it .. II think that it is my subscribe .. because I defined the values in my subscribe .. thx .. I use angular ...

Comment: Where does `this.jsonUsers` get it's values and where are you assigning them?

Comment: I edited my post with a screen of my code .. you can check it

Answer (score 0):

looks like that array has no elements on it, those that you see in the console's output are object's keys. Try something like this, and let us know what you see

```
let jsonUsers = [];
getUser() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.jsonUsers);
    keys.forEach((k, i) => {
        const element = this.jsonUsers[k];
        console.log(element.code)
    })
}
```

or another option could be using `for...in`

```
let jsonUsers = [];
getUser() {
    for (let k in this.jsonUsers) {
        const element = this.jsonUsers[k];
        console.log(element.code)
    }
}
```

note that `this.jsonUsers` is a different variable than `jsonUsers`, keep that in mind

Comment: I tried it, but the value of `keys` is `null` ... it is strange this things

Comment: did you tried `for...in` yet? try: `for (let k in this.jsonUsers) { console.log(this.jsonUsers[k].code) }`

Comment: I tried it, but I think it is my subscribe.. because I defined the values in my subscribe with angular